# PyObject_CallObject failing on bytearray method

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

In the following code I create a pointer to a PyObject, representing a bytearray,  using the Python C API. I then extract the method "endswith" from the bytearray and try to call it on the original bytearray itself, expecting it to return `Py_True.` However, it returns `NULL` and the program prints "very sad".

```
#include<Python.h>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    //make a one-byte byte array
    PyObject* oneByteArray = PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize("a", 1);
    //get the method "endswith" from the object at oneByteArray
    PyObject* arrayEndsWith = PyObject_GetAttrString(oneByteArray, "endswith");
    //ask python if "a" ends with "a"
    PyObject* shouldbetrue = PyObject_CallObject(arrayEndsWith, oneByteArray);

    if (shouldbetrue == Py_True) std::cout << "happy\n";
    if(shouldbetrue == NULL)std::cout << "very sad\n";

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked in Python that for bytearrays, `foo` and `bar`, `foo.endswith(bar)` returns a Boolean. I also added `PyCallable_Check(arrayEndsWith)` to the code above and verified that the object is callable. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the line [`PyErr_PrintEx(1)`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html) it helpfully tells you:

> TypeError: argument list must be a tuple

This is confirmed by [the documentation for `PyObject_CallObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html):

> Call a callable Python object callable_object, with arguments given by
>   the tuple args.

There's a whole bunch of ways of calling functions from the C-api. I picked one that doesn't require a tuple and it works for me (but pick the one you like):

```
PyObject* shouldbetrue = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(arrayEndsWith, oneByteArray,NULL);
```

Comment: `PyObject_IsTrue(shouldbetrue)` maybe too